# Wildfly Singleton Service election in cluster gives Out of Memory/Metaspace Issues

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-16

Wildfly runs its Singleton Service in cluster in midnight or mid day like

```
2022-03-18 00:00:07,151 INFO  [org.wildfly.clustering.server] (LegacyDistributedSingletonService - 1) WFLYCLSV0003: alp-esb-app02:masterdata-batch-02 elected as the singleton provider of the jboss.deployment.unit."masterdata-emp-org-powerdata-1.4.war".installer service
```

In 3 clusters, Many integrations in 02 jumps to 03 and vice versa and in between we come up with Metaspace? Basically it un deploys one integrations and deploys other integration from other server.

Why such behavior and why it always have metaspace and how could it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

This would happen if one of your cluster members is removed from the cluster (based on criteria of your JGroups failure detection configuration).  Your logs should indicate the reason.